# How to pass and get color code value with get request

Tags: php, get

I have to pass color code with query string url. Right now I am passing it directly but it will not giving me desire output.

```
$color = "#ff0000";
$name = "test";
$download = "1";

$url = "http://localhost/demo?name=".$name."&color=".$color."&download=".$download." ";
```

With above url I got below output.

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://localhost/demo
    [name] => test
)
```

**Desire output:**

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://localhost/demo
    [name] => test
    [color] => #fe8c1a
    [download] => 1
)
```

Please help me which one is the best way to solve this problem.

**Note: I have used urlencode($color). Its working fine but I dont know its correct or not. Also tell me if any other method is better than this.**

Comment: using urlencode is correct. You can go on with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `urlencode()` works fine:

```
$url = "http://localhost/demo?name=".$name."&color=".urlencode($color)."&download=".$download." ";
```

If you want another alternative, then use [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php):

```
$query_string = http_build_query(array(
    'name' => $name,
    'color' => $color,
    'download' => $download,
));

$url = "http://localhost/demo?{$query_string}";
```

Comment: @RuchishParikh, I have tested this answer on my local machine. And it works perfectly.